# Magento 2.4 allow admin to add out of stock product from admin order

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

In magento 2.4 we can not add out of stock product while placing order from admin. I have requirement that admin should be able to order from admin side even the products are out of stock. I see the backorder but I want it only for admin side.

Comment: This is the M2 core bug.

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Posted, try now

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way until M2 fixes that core bug.

**app/code/SR/Sales/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition">
        <plugin name="sr_disable_stock_check_for_admin"
                type="SR\Sales\Plugin\Model\InventorySales\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition"
                sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/SR/Sales/Plugin/Model/InventorySales/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsSalableWithReservationsCondition.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SR\Sales\Plugin\Model\InventorySales\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition;

use Magento\InventorySales\Model\IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition\IsSalableWithReservationsCondition as BaseIsSalableWithReservationsCondition;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory;

class IsSalableWithReservationsCondition
{
    /**
     * @var ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $productSalableResultFactory;

    /**
     * IsSalableWithReservationsCondition constructor.
     *
     * @param ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory $productSalableResultFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductSalableResultInterfaceFactory $productSalableResultFactory
    ) {
        $this->productSalableResultFactory = $productSalableResultFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param BaseIsSalableWithReservationsCondition $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param string $sku
     * @param int $stockId
     * @param float $requestedQty
     * @return ProductSalableResultInterface
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        BaseIsSalableWithReservationsCondition $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        string $sku,
        int $stockId,
        float $requestedQty
    ): ProductSalableResultInterface {
        return $this->productSalableResultFactory->create(['errors' => []]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. While adding product it is not coming in this function.

Comment: This is the working code. Maybe you made some mistake. You need to adjust this code into a new custom module.

Comment: I added log it should generate log file, but it is not generating. Are you sure this function is running while adding product while placing order from admin ?

Comment: I tried, I created new module with same code but it is not working. My magento version is  2.4.1

Comment: I will check with M2.4.1 CE later.

Comment: @SohelRana did you get around to this yet? We're facing the same issue :D

Comment: Does not fix/allow admin to add out of stock product for M2.4.5-p4 with MSI modules disabled

Answer (score 0):

[image]

just comment this code, to make out of stock work in admin

Comment: Lacks context no longer relevant for M2.4 equivalent classes

Answer (score 0):

My solution: change function get Config backorders

1- Create di.xml file in your module
Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration">
    <plugin name="custom_get_backorders" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomBackorders" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

2- Create CustomBackorders.php file

Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomBackorders.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;

class CustomBackorders
{

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $_backendSession;

    public function __construct(
        BackendSession $backendSession
    )
    {
        $this->_backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    public function afterGetBackorders(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->_backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $result = (int)1;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - please may I ask which Magento 2 version does this work for? I have tried it on Magento 2.4.3 and it isn't working for me.

Comment: Does not fix/allow admin to add out of stock product for M2.4.5-p4 with MSI modules disabled